# I'm not able to find Hibernate 2.* option in JPA Facet plataform

Tags: hibernate, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

[image: JPA not able to find Hibernate plataform]

Hi, I'm trying to configure JPA 2.1 through "Project Facets". Why can't I see "Hibernate 2.x" in plataform JPA Facet selection menu after selecting JPA 2.1 and going through further configuration?

I have Eclipse Luna and also JBoss Tools.

Maven:

```
    <javaee-api.version>7.0</javaee-api.version>
    <hibernate-core.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
    <!-- Java EE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

You have to install under Eclipse Market Red Hat Jboss Developer Studio (also jboss tools)